# How can I customize the widget on the homepage on Magento2 Luma theme?

Tags: magento2, widget, luma-theme

I have been trying to locate the code for the widget to no avail. I'll like some help with customizing the widget.

Here is the screenshot of the widget:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luma theme homepage content comes from widget.
First of All, go to Admin panel,

```
Content -> Widgets
```

Now click on Home Page widget.
You can check it using widget option tab,
You have display Block with Home Page Block.

Now go to `Content -> Blocks` and find static block with title is "Home Page Block" to edit.
You can customize content from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Luma theme used a widget to add a static block to homepage, if you want to edit content of this, please go to Content > Blocks and find static block with title is "Home Page Block" to edit.